# How to add Section Header in ListView List Item

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to Develop "History of Country" Android Application. But I have a problem. I can not put Country Header in Listview List Item. I want to put Header; Such as "Africa : North Africa", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Asia", "North Asia", "West & Central Asia", "South & Southeast Asia", "Europe", "North & Central America", "North America", "Oceania", "South America".
**Here My Source Code** : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k66xonom9up1yif/Country%20Search%20ListView.zip?dl=0

Here my Sample code: 
**Search_Country.java**

```html
package com.nasir.search;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Search_Country extends ListActivity {
 
 private EditText SearchText;
 private ListView ListText;
 
 private String[] Number_List = {
  // Africa : North Africa
  "Algeria", "Egypt", "Libya", "Morocco", "Tunisia", "Western Sahara", 

  // Sub-Saharan Africa
  "Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Chad", "Comoros", "Congo", 
  "Côte d'Ivoire", "Djibouti", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Kenya",
  "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mozambique", "Namibia", 
  "Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", 
  "Sudan", "Swaziland", "Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe", 
  
  // Asia : 
  // East Asia
  "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Korea", "Macao", "Mongolia", "Taiwan", 
  
  // North Asia
  "Belarus", "Moldova", "Russian Federation", "Ukraine", 
  
  // West & Central Asia
  "Afghanistan", "Armenia", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Cyprus", "Georgia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Israel", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan",
  "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lebanon", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Qatar", "Saudi Arabia", "Tajikistan", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", 
  "United Arab Emirates", "Uzbekistan", "Yemen", 
  
  // South & Southeast Asia
  "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "Brunei", "Cambodia", "India", "Indonesia", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Myanmar", "Nepal", 
  "Philippines", "Singapore", "Sri Lanka", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Viet Nam", 
  
  // Europe
  "Åland Islands", "Albania", "Andorra", "Austria", "Belgium", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", 
  "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Faroe Islands", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Gibraltar", "Greece", 
  "Greenland", "Guernsey", "Hungary", "Iceland", "", "", "", "", "Ireland", "Jersey", "Latvia", "Liechtenstein", 
  "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Monaco", "Montenegro", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", 
  "Romania", "San Marino", "Serbia", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Sweden", "Switzerland", 
  "United Kingdom", 
  
  // North & Central America
  "Caribbean Islands", "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Aruba", "Bahamas", "Barbados", "Bermuda", "Cayman Islands", 
  "Bonaire", "Cuba", "Dominica", "Curaçao", "Guadeloupe", "Haiti", "Jamaica", "Martinique", "Montserrat", "Puerto Rico", 
  "Saint Bathélemy", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Martin (French Part)", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
  "Sint Maarten (Dutch Part)", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Virgin Islands, British", "Virgin Islands, U.S.",
  
  // Mesoamerica (or Central America)
  "Belize", "Costa Rica", "El Salvador", "Guatemala", "Honduras", "Mexico", "Nicaragua", "Panama",
  
  // North America
  "Canada", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "United States", 

  // Oceania
  "American Samoa", "Australia", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Cook Islands", "Fiji", "Guam", "Kiribati",
  "Marshall Islands", "Micronesia", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", 
  "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Pitcairn", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Tuvalu", "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
  "Vanuatu", "Wallis and Futuna", 

  // South America
  "Argentina", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Chile", "Colombia", "Ecuador", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "French Guiana", "Guyana",
  "Paraguay", "Peru", "Suriname", "Uruguay", "Venezuela"};
 
 private ArrayList<String> array_sort;
 int textlength = 0;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.search_country);

  SearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.listview_search);
  ListText = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

  array_sort = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Number_List));
  setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));

  SearchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
  {
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
   {

   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
   {

   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
   {
    textlength = SearchText.getText().length();
    array_sort.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < Number_List.length; i++) 
    {
     if (textlength <= Number_List[i].length()) 
     {      
      if(Number_List[i].toUpperCase().contains(SearchText.getText().toString().toUpperCase().trim()))
      {
       array_sort.add(Number_List[i]);
      }
     }
    }
    AppendList(array_sort);
   }
  });

  ListText.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
  {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    if( array_sort.get(position).equals("Afghanistan")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Search_Country.this, Country_Details.class);                            
        intent.putExtra("header", getString(R.string.html_afganistan));                                       
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if ( array_sort.get(position).equals("Albania")){
     Intent intent = new Intent(Search_Country.this, Country_Details.class);
     intent.putExtra("header", getString(R.string.html_albenia));
     startActivity(intent);
    }
    
    else if ( array_sort.get(position).equals("Algeria")){
     Intent intent = new Intent(Search_Country.this, Country_Details.class);
     intent.putExtra("header", getString(R.string.html_algeria));
     startActivity(intent);
    }
    
    else if ( array_sort.get(position).equals("Brazil")){
     Intent intent = new Intent(Search_Country.this, Country_Details.class);
     intent.putExtra("header", getString(R.string.html_brazil));
     startActivity(intent);
    }
    
   }
  });
 }

 public void AppendList(ArrayList<String> str) 
 {
  setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));
 }

 public class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
 {
  Activity cntx;

  public bsAdapter(Activity context) 
  {
   this.cntx = context;
  }

  public int getCount()
  {
   return array_sort.size();
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) 
  {
   return array_sort.get(position);
  }

  public long getItemId(int position)
  {
   return array_sort.size();
  }

  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
   View row = null;
   LayoutInflater inflater = cntx.getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_country_listview, null);
   TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listview_seacrh_text);
   tv.setText(array_sort.get(position));
   return row;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: There are numerous libraries for list view headers. Any search engine will find some for you.

Comment: I need Simple Header

Comment: You can use [Expandable ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) if you have only two levels.

Comment: I do not want to use Expandable ListView

Answer (score 35):

**Screen Shot**

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Search..."
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCountry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_section.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D8D8D8"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSectionTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Section"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView lvCountry;
    private EditText edtSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
        lvCountry = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCountry);

        ArrayList<Item> countryList = new ArrayList<MainActivity.Item>();
        // Header
        countryList.add(new SectionItem("Asia"));
        // State Name
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("India"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("China"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Hong Kong"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Nepal"));

        // Header
        countryList.add(new SectionItem("North Asia"));
        // State Name
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Belarus"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Moldova"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Russian Federation"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Ukraine"));

        // Header
        countryList.add(new SectionItem("North America"));
        // State Name
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Canada"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Saint Pierre and Miquelon"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("United States"));

        // Header
        countryList.add(new SectionItem("North & Central America"));
        // State Name
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Caribbean Islands"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Anguilla"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Antigua and Barbuda"));
        countryList.add(new EntryItem("Aruba"));

        // set adapter
        final CountryAdapter adapter = new CountryAdapter(this, countryList);
        lvCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvCountry.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // filter on text change
        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(adapter != null)
                {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * row item
     */
    public interface Item {
        public boolean isSection();
        public String getTitle();
    }

    /**
     * Section Item
     */
    public class SectionItem implements Item {
        private final String title;

        public SectionItem(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSection() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Entry Item
     */
    public class EntryItem implements Item {
        public final String title;

        public EntryItem(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSection() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter
     */
    public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Item> item;
        private ArrayList<Item> originalItem;

        public CountryAdapter() {
            super();
        }

        public CountryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> item) {
            this.context = context;
            this.item = item;
            //this.originalItem = item;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return item.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return item.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (item.get(position).isSection()) {
                // if section header
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_section, parent, false);
                TextView tvSectionTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSectionTitle);
                tvSectionTitle.setText(((SectionItem) item.get(position)).getTitle());
            }
            else
            {
                // if item
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
                TextView tvItemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemTitle);
                tvItemTitle.setText(((EntryItem) item.get(position)).getTitle());
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        /**
         * Filter
         */
        public Filter getFilter()
        {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                    item = (ArrayList<Item>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("null")
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<Item> filteredArrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();


                    if(originalItem == null || originalItem.size() == 0)
                    {
                        originalItem = new ArrayList<Item>(item);
                    }

                    /*
                     * if constraint is null then return original value
                     * else return filtered value
                     */
                    if(constraint == null && constraint.length() == 0)
                    {
                        results.count = originalItem.size();
                        results.values = originalItem;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                        for (int i = 0; i < originalItem.size(); i++) 
                        {
                            String title = originalItem.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                            if(title.startsWith(constraint.toString()))
                            {
                                filteredArrayList.add(originalItem.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        results.count = filteredArrayList.size();
                        results.values = filteredArrayList;
                    }

                    return results;
                }
            };

            return filter;
        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sectionheader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks,
But this project does not have search UI.
Please send Link with search UI

Comment: @NasirBPM Search UI you have to make by your own .. No one will provide you spoon feeding. This example is best for Section Header. You can add search UI in this. Do some R&D

Comment: Give me Source Code of "Section Header Listview in android"

Comment: My Eclipse IDE not Support "appcompat_v7"
Please Send Source code without "appcompat_v7"

Comment: Don't ask for the entire code base or any kind of spoon feeding, rather try to implement yourself and share if you are facing any issue!

Comment: Wonderful... Helped me a lot... :)

Comment: how to add multiple items in EntryItems

Comment: like title , subtitle , category like this

Comment: For multiple items you can update layout_item.xml with multiple views like TextView (tvItemTitle).

Comment: @PiyushMalaviya thank you so much for replying me I know but I am stuck in Models how to add new data when we are fetching from Item getTitle